# prestashop's live url redirecting to my localhost

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am facing a unique problem. When I open my website which hosted on a server it redirects to my localhost. I am not able to find the solution or debug whats causing this.

Comment: It seems like you might of made some changes to your Hosts file. I would start there.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have recently uploaded your site that you developed on a local machine, up to its live server.

At which point there will be multiple instances of your "website url" saved in the Database as well as potentially the .htaccess and maybe even a config file depending on the platform ( im not massively familiar with prestashop ).

Check:

- .htaccess for RewriteRule /localhost/index.php/ or something similar.
- Database for any instance of your localhost directory
- Any config files
- Try on a different browser to make sure there is no caching going on

Comment: can u explain a bit more .on which database table is responsible for this.

Comment: Try YOURPREFIX_shop_url table

Answer (score 0):

Is very easy actually. In Backoffice go to SEO & URL Preferences and check your domain URL, should have localhost address yet. Additionaly delete or rename .htaccess file in your Prestashop root. You could generate it again later.

Good luck